# Enable HTTPS/SSL on Fuseki server?

Tags: linux, sparql, jena, fuseki

Is it possible to configure the Fuseki server to run over HTTPS?

Currently: http://mylinuxbox:3030/ <-- OK

Desired: https://mylinuxbox:3030/ <-- results in error

Comment: here is a discussion about this on the jena users list for Fuseki v2 (development).

For Fuseki1, you define it via the Jetty configuration setup. --jetty-config=

Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119849/how-to-configure-a-jetty-ssl-connector-under-fuseki

Comment: Another way is to put a reverse proxy in and put Fuseki behind that.  If you already know how to set up httpd/nginx/... for https, that might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndyS's comments, which seem like they probably answer the question:

> here is a discussion about this on the jena users list for Fuseki v2
>   (development). For Fuseki1, you define it via the Jetty configuration
>   setup. --jetty-config=
>
> Another way is to put a reverse proxy in and put Fuseki behind that. If you already know how to set up httpd/nginx/... for https,
>   that might be easier.